# How to remove hyphen symbol in a string and add caps after hyphen in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove hyphen in a string and add first letter caps after the hyphen in a string.

```
var value = "main-component";
var newValue = newValue.replace('-','').charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1); //mainComponent
```

Output should be like newValue is mainComponent.

How to do it in javascript.

Comment: You are asking how to convert kebab-case to camelCase. And as such it is a dupe.

Comment: @mplungjan: i got answer

Comment: I know. It was a dupe, but of course easier to find when using the agreed nomenklature